# Has there been progress for URDF transform jitter in RVIZ?

Tags: ros, rviz, transforms, urdf, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From my [ros-users post](https://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20101217.042334.a4610002.gl.html):

*So I have been following the really nice (R2D2) tutorials on URDF, thanks a
lot for those! I've managed to get our robot model into RVIZ and follow
base_link, but the transforms on the URDF besides base_link all seem to time
lag, causing some jittery looking motion:*

*http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GiQUc8FG6m8*

*We originally noticed that the static TFs defaulted publishing
from joint_state_publisher at 10Hz, so we set it to 100Hz. This upped the
maximum rate published to that of our base_link (~50Hz from our odom
source), but this is what you see in the video.*

*The model does not jitter in RVIZ if the target and fixed frame are set to
base_link, but does jitter when fixed frame is odom. We are playing data from a recorded bag file using --clock and have set
use_sim_time to true.
I've attached a copy of the xacro file I use to generate our urdf in case
I've made a mistake in there.*

*Thanks,*

*- Chad*

It would be nice to have the links update and move [synchronously for the robot model](https://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20101217.183439.eef0c0fd.gl.html).  Is this something that should have a ticket made?  Are there other solutions than editing the [timestamps in the bagfile](https://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20101217.090809.0e2f24f8.gl.html)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9142/has-there-been-progress-for-urdf-transform-jitter-in-rviz?/) by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4541 on 2011-02-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that the most proper fix is to [file a ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/newticket?component=visualization&type=defect&&visualization) against rviz to update the robot model atomically.

The development version of tf2 deals with static transforms natively, however that won't fix this problem completely if some of the joints are not static.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [littleghost](https://answers.ros.org/users/33922/littleghost/) on 2019-02-01**:
The link is broken, could you post a new link?